IF statement returning false and not going to next part of formula
I am trying to write an if statement to read a cell that shows the quarter, Cell B3, and based on that, sum the 3 months of that quarter of a separate tab within the same workbook. It works for the first portion of the if statement, B3=1, but if the cell that it is referencing changes to 2, it is returning false
=IF(B3=1,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!B4:D4,IF(B3=2,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!E4:G4,IF(B3=3,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!H4:J4,IF(B3=4,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!K4:M4,))))))))
I have not found a way to set this up without it returning false or #N/A!. I thought of trying Offset, but cannot find the right way to have it skip the correct amount of columns to include the full quarter of data that is laid out by month.

Your formula should work but clearly it is missing the closing parenthesis for each of those SUM() function: =IF(B3=1,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!B4:D4),IF(B3=2,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!E4:G4),IF(B3=3,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!H4:J4),IF(B3=4,SUM('2024 Product by Month'!K4:M4),))))))))

Or you can use something like this may be: =SUM(CHOOSE(B3,'2024 Product by Month'!B4:D4,'2024 Product by Month'!E4:G4,'2024 Product by Month'!H4:J4,'2024 Product by Month'!K4:M4))

=SUM(INDEX('2024 Product by Month'!4:4,,(B3-1)*3+2):INDEX('2024 Product by Month'!4:4,,(B3-1)*3+4))

=SUM(INDEX('2024 Product by Month'!4:4,,B3*3-{-1,0,1}))
